# How to add colums to a blank data frame columns by columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, addition, multiple-columns

I try to create a data.fame, and then add some columns to this data.frame.

I try following code, but it does not work:

```
test.dim <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=0, ncol=4))
names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
colnames(test.dim) <- names

for (i in 1:4) {
    name = names[i]
    # do some calculations, at last get another data.fame named x.data

    mean.data <- apply(x.data, 1, mean)
    test.dim[, name] <- mean.data

}
```

Comment: please format your code appropriately. And where does the object `x.data` come from?

Comment: There are probably much better ways to do what you need to do. Can you explain in words and with a small example what problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: To Ananda: In fact, I have two tables, I extract some information from the first table, and then use the information get to select columns in the second table, and then calculate the mean for selected blocks. at last, I create a table the mean values with the information got from the first table as the column names. I hope it is clear for you. That's why I create a blank data.frame, and then add values columns by columns

Comment: It sounds like you'd better use `merge`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually one would already have a data.frame (call it `df`) and simply add frames by calling `df$newColName = values` or `df[,newColNames] = frame_of_values`.

Your question indicates that you are separating the creation of your values from putting them in the data frame (which I do not recommend). But if you really want to start from a zero row zero col frame here are some options:

```
colnamesToAdd = LETTERS[1:4]
test.dim = data.frame(  matrix(rep(NA),length(colnamesToAdd),nrow=1)   )
colnames(test.dim) = colnamesToAdd
test.dim = test.dim[-1,]
```

Another option:

```
colnamesToAdd = LETTERS[1:4]
test.dim = data.frame("USELESS" = NA)
test.dim[,colnamesToAdd] = NA
test.dim = test.dim[-1,-1]
```

If you are looking to add a mean to your table and repeat it for every factor:

```
library(data.table); 
test.dim = data.table("FACTOR" = sample(letters[1:4],100,replace=TRUE), "VALUE" = runif(100), "MEAN" = NA)
means = test.dim[,list(AVG=mean(VALUE)),by="FACTOR"]
# without data.table: by(test.dim$VALUE, test.dim$FACTOR, mean)
for(x in 1:nrow(means)) { test.dim$MEAN[test.dim$FACTOR==means$FACTOR[x]] = means$AVG[x] } # normally I would use the foreach package instead of this last for loop
```

Comment: Many thanks to Hans, The first option is good. I change my idea to add it column by column, I use for to add each values individually. So I solve it. Thank you so much about how to define blank data.frame.